# Efficient merging of multiple tables

Tags: pandas, sql

Suppose you have 3 or more tables with different observations or hypotheses to be merged with a inner join.  The tables have partially overlapping columns, and when completely merged yield a reduced set of combined conditions.  What are some algorithms for joining multiple tables (more than two at a time) so that they can be merged in a memory-efficient way?   Below is a toy example for three observers with different sets of possible scenarios:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

set1 = pd.DataFrame([[who,how] for who,how in itertools.product(['Green','Scarlet','Mustard','Plum'],['Dagger','Candlestick','Rope','Wrench'])],columns=['who','how'])
set2 = pd.DataFrame([[where,how] for where,how in itertools.product(['Ballroom','Conservatory','Billiard Room','Study','Hall','Library'],['Revolver','Rope','Wrench','Pipe'])],columns=['where','how'])
set3 = pd.DataFrame([[where,who] for where,who in itertools.product(['Kitchen','Hall','Lounge','Dining Room','Study'],['Scarlet','Plum','Peacock','White'])],columns=['where','who'])

sets12 = pd.merge(set1,set2)

pd.merge(sets12,set3)
```

Doing an iterative merging of pairs of tables using `pd.merge` will create a temporary table (possibly much) larger than the inputs, even if the final output is small.  Though I suspect it is a well-studied problem, I'm unable to find information on ways to efficiently arrive at the final table without creating the temporary table (`set12` in the example).  Is this done automatically with proper database engines but is just missing in `pandas`?